# Filter out data in entity framework using linq in .net core

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have below code for which I need to filter out the data for passed UserIds and with Start Date/End Date. The userid's are being passed as a List.

So, for the same I am first getting the data from the Database and then filtering for the userids passed.
So till now this working fine. After that I need to filter data for start date and end date, where I am facing a problem.

Below is my code for the same.

```
var details = dataContext.Period
              .Include(x => x.PeriodUsers)
              .ThenInclude(x => x.Summary)
              .ThenInclude(x => x.SummaryDetails)
              .Where(x => x.PeriodId == _periodId)
              .ToListAsync();


var summaryDetails =  details              
                      .SelectMany(x => x.PeriodUsers)
                      .SelectMany(x => x.Summary)
                      .SelectMany(x => x.SummaryDetails)
                      .Where(y => _periodusers.Contains(y.UserId)).ToList();
```

So, now this start date and end date are in Summary table. So, when I tried to filter on Summary model using summaryDetails object, I am not able to get the Summary list, instead I am only getting the class object for 'Summary'.

So, my question is how can I filter out the data using UserId's and Start/EndDate. So, that my results will be in particular one list.

Comment: I think you should post your related model classes, tell more about your requirement (filtering on db or locally). This kind of question (linq-related) should be made clear to have good answers.

Comment: @XamDev - would it be possible for you to provide the model code for Period, PeriodUsers, Summary and SummaryDetails. It will be very difficult to provide you with the Linq query details without it.